# React route doesn't work on paths other than "/", using webpack

Tags: reactjs, express, web, webpack, routes

### The Problem

I am trying to route to `/song/new`, but I get this message (with no additional error in console):

```
Cannot GET /song/new
```

The root path `/` works.

### What I tried

- using exact on the root path
- adding to **webpack.config.js** `publicPath`(in devserver and output) and `historyApiFallback: true,`
- updating the version of the packages I have
- adding     `<base href="/" />` to **index.html**

Here is the code.

### dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
"@apollo/client": "^3.0.0-beta.20",
"@apollo/react-hoc": "^3.1.3",
"@babel/core": "^7.7.7",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.7",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.7.4",
"apollo-client": "^2.6.8",
"axios": "^0.19.1",
"babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
"body-parser": "^1.16.0",
"connect-mongo": "^1.3.2",
"css-loader": "^3.4.2",
"express": "^4.14.0",
"express-graphql": "^0.6.1",
"express-session": "^1.15.0",
"graphql": "^0.8.2",
"html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
"lodash": "^4.17.4",
"mongoose": "^5.8.7",
"passport": "^0.3.2",
"passport-local": "^1.0.0",
"react": "^16.12.0",
"react-apollo": "^3.1.3",
"react-dom": "^16.12.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
"style-loader": "^0.13.1",
"webpack": "^4.41.5",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.7.2"
```

### client/index.html

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
   href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css">
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
   <base href="/" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

### client/index.js

```
const Root = () => {
return (
 <ApolloProvider client={client}>
   <Router>
     <App/>
   </Router>
 </ApolloProvider>
 )
 };
```

### App.js

```
const App = () => {
return (
    <div className="container">
        <Switch>

            <Route exact path="/">
                <SongList />
            </Route>

            <Route path="song/new">
                <SongCreate />
            </Route>

        </Switch>
    </div>
)
}
```

### webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
 mode: 'development',
 entry: './client/index.js',
 output: {
   filename: 'bundle.js',
 },
 module: {
   rules: [
     {
       use: [{
         loader: 'babel-loader',
         options: {
           presets: [
            ['@babel/preset-env']
           ]
         }
       }],
       test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: [
         "style-loader",
       {
          loader: "css-loader",
        }
      ]
    }
   ]
 },
 devServer: {
   publicPath: '/',
   historyApiFallback: true,
},
 plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: 'client/index.html'
  })
 ]
};
```

And this is were the webpack is executed:

### server.js

```
const webpackMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackConfig = require('../webpack.config.js');
app.use(webpackMiddleware(webpack(webpackConfig)));
```

Answer (score 1):

*Working with the latest version of react-router and react-router-dom (5.1.2) as of March 2020.*

```
Cannot GET /song/new
```

You are receiving this error because:

1. The backend server is not setup to redirect unknown GET requests to
   React.
2. You are using Router (this is a low level router, you should use a high level router).

The solution is to use `<HashRouter />` or `<MemoryRouter />`, **not** `<Router />` or `<BrowserRouter />`

---

HashRouter will add a hash into your route.

Example: `http://localhost:4000/#/`

Everything beyond the # is ignored by modern browsers and no request is actually sent, meaning Node/Express will never receive a request, which ultimately means React can navigate on its own without needing to configure the backend with middleware.

BrowserRouter can be thought of as normal routing.

Example: `http://localhost:4000/users/new`

This is a valid URL and the request will be handled by Express. If the backend is not configured to work with React you are certainly going to have issues.

**Implementation:**

```
// Make sure this is imported from react-router-dom NOT react-router!!!

import {HashRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <HashRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" component={App} exact/>
                ....define more routes here!!
            </Switch>
        </HashRouter>
    </ApolloProvider>,
    document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

Notice that we do not need the hashHistory import nor do we need IndexRoute. If you wish to redirect users through event listeners use the history object on props (provided to us by React Router):

```
this.props.history.push("/some/route/goes/here");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the publicPath. It might be an error with the path of the application.